# signature verification in my c# project with accord.net

Tags: c#, accord.net

I want to do signature verification in my c# project and accord.net seems to be providing a utility to match images. Can anybody please let me know which class to better use for signature verification in accord.net ? I want to verify how much similarity there is in the written cheque against the signature image I already have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.